# Detect origin domain of a `<a href>` request with missing referrer

Tags: html

Is there a way to detect/guess the origin domain of a request coming from a `<a href>` link in case the referer information was hidden with `rel=noreferrer` and no way to modify the link?

Answer (score 0):

No, and if there were, that would imply a serious bug in the implementation of `rel=noreferrer`.